# How do I meet Oracle at the clock tower?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

I'm at the clock tower, parked at the glowing white "Here's the objective, dummy!" icon and nothing is happening. I've searched all over the clock tower and can't find Oracle.

**How do I get inside the clock tower to meet Oracle?** I'm "stuck" doing side missions until then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hit your detective vision (up on D-PAD) to find the location of the hidden door on the roof.

[image: clock tower]

Comment: Ah crap, I took a picture of this a long time ago but forgot to write an answer.  I'll add it to this one anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there's a 1mm-wide spot on the north side of the tower where the game prompts you to hit a button to enter (X on PS4).

Here's a video: